# what is the issue with the below code?

Tags: c++, string

The question is to replace the spaces contained in a string with a "%20". So basically need to insert this in a string wherever there is a space. Therefore, I want to replace all spaces with %20 but only partial string is getting replaced. I can see the correct o/p in the replace function

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int spaces(char* s,int size)   /*calculate number of spaces*/
{
    int nspace=0;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(s[i]==' ')
        {
          nspace++;
        }
    }
  return nspace;
}

int len_new_string(char* inp,int l)   /*calculate the length of the new string*/
{
     int new_length=l+spaces(inp,l)*2;
     return new_length;
}

char* replace(char* s,int length)  /*function to replace the spaces within a string*/
{
   int len=len_new_string(s,length);
   char new_string[len];
   int j=0;
   for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
   {
      if(s[i]==' ')     /*code to insert %20 if space is found*/
      {
        new_string[j]='%';
        new_string[j+1]='2';
        new_string[j+2]='0';
        j=j+3;
      }
      else    /*copy the original string if no space*/
      {
         new_string[j]=s[i];
         j++;
      }
   }
 cout<<"Replaced String: "<<new_string<<endl;
 return s=new_string;
 }


int main()
{
  char str[]="abc def ghi ";
  int length=sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0]);
  cout<<"String is: "<<str<<endl;
  char *new_str=replace(str,length);
  cout<<"Replaced String is: "<<new_str<<endl;
 }
```

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE]._

Comment: You are returning a pointer to a local array. When you try to display `new_string`, it is already gone.

Answer (score 1):

The char array should go out of scope and be released. The only reason you don't get a segfault is that apparently no other program has reserved the memory in that spot yet. To avoid this, try using a char array with padding, handing it over by reference or pointer and filling it in place:

```
void replace(char *in, char *out, size_t length)
{
  /* copy as-is for non-spaces, insert replacement for spaces */
}

int main()
{
  char str[]="abc def ghi";
  size_t buflen(strlen(str)+2*spaces(str, strlen(str)));
  char output[buflen+1];
  memset(output, 0, buflen+1);
  replace(str, output, strlen(str));
}
```

Another option is to `new[]` the return array (remember to `delete[]` it afterwards, then!) or, which I think you left out for a reason, use `std::string` all along to avoid the array issue.

Comment: _"The only reason you don't get a segfault is that apparently no other program has reserved the memory in that spot yet."_ No, the reason is undefined behavior, anything can happen.